# Application needs access to files, but user is not allowed to access them

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10

I have a requirement that my Windows GUI application writes log files. But for auditing purposes, certain users that run the application are not allowed access those files. Is there any way to handle the fact that the application needs different file permissions than the user running it? A couple suggestions have been made to me are to write a Windows service to manage the logging or write to the Windows Event Log. This would be a major change, as we're already writing to files on disk, so I am hoping I can accomplish this by running the app as a different user.

I know I can do this by using runas with saved credentials, but this is a security risk. And I thought about using the Task Scheduler, but it seems this won't display the UI for the logged in user.

Comment: Logging to the Windows Event log is the right way to do this; it will make it possible for your systems administrators to handle those logs according to your company standards.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, Event log would be the ideal way to do this. It would be possible to set those permissions but it seems fragile. If your user needs elevation for the application that could supersede the rights of your log user and pose risk or leave its sandbox and 'lose connectivity'. 
It also poses the risk of creating a large amount of logs that the user then has no rights to clean up. You would need another administrative process to do this; snowball effect.

Comment: I agree, but we do have three levels of users, one of which has the permissions to export and then subsequently delete logs

Comment: There really is no way to give an "application" permissions in Windows, only a user. The only way you could do as you described is if there was one process that was the GUI and one process that handled the log creation. You could potentially give each different user rights (runas or service for the logger). If it is a single process, you could move logs away with an automation task so the user cannot read them on an interval? (Lock, write, move to protected space, repeat). Conceivably, (unless the application simply crashed) a user could not read logs with the GUI open.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't quite get it so maybe my answer will be stupid, but why don't you simply give all users right to write to that file. Only write access. They will not be able to read it or delete it. Better yet, if they don't have access to the dir where the LOG is located, give them just "Traverse" right on the root folder. That way, they can write to file and still can not access the dir. Again, sorry if I misunderstood something.
[image]